# Generating a dynamic matrix from reference table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have the following reference

```
corr = pd.DataFrame({'i':['a','b'],'a':[.1,.2],'b':[.2,.1]}).set_index('i')
```

[image]

I also have some vector values. The length will always change so I'm only using 6 to show what I am trying to achieve.

```
vectors = pd.DataFrame({'val':['a','b','a','a','b']})
```

I would like to use these values to generate a 5x5 matrix 'X' such that:

[image]

5x5 because vector len(vector) = 5

The closest I can think of is a map function, that generates only one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) twice, once for columns and once for rows:

```
out = corr.reindex(vectors['val']).reindex(vectors['val'], axis=1)
```

Note that duplicate column names, while supported, is not recommended. For example `out['a']` would return a dataframe, while most of the case it returns a series.

Comment: df in this case would be what?

Comment: @RealRageDontQuit updated. muscle memory `df` for a generic dataframe.

Comment: I added the link to reindex. Feel free to revert the changes if not ok. I agree with duplicate columns not being recommended. I can't think of a use case from the back of my head.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and use both `index` and `columns` arguments with `vectors["val"]`

```
idx = vectors["val"] # vectors["val"].tolist() to avoid naming axes `val`.
corr.reindex(index=idx, columns=idx)

val    a    b    a    a    a    b
val                              
a    0.1  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
b    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1
a    0.1  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
a    0.1  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
a    0.1  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.1  0.2
b    0.2  0.1  0.2  0.2  0.2  0.1
```

Answer (score -2):

DataFrame.reindex twice, once for columns and once for rows:

```html
out = corr.reindex(vectors['val']).reindex(vectors['val'], axis=1)
```

Although duplicate column names are supported, they are not recommended

Comment: You've basically copy-pasted [Quang's answer from 4 hours prior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813693/13138364). Please don't do that. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for proper ways to contribute.

Comment: Wow. It's not just the _code_ that's copied, but even some of the wording.

Comment: This answer is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412820).